# android - out of memory exception when get drawable from assets

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

In my android projects there is custom Grid View with images. Images are comes from assets folder.

Here it is code for get drawable from assets folder:

```
Drawable imgDrawable = Drawable.createFromStream(myContext.getAssets().open(imgPath),null);
```

after scrolling grid view its give out of memory exception
Log Displays:

```
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:657)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at org.Infoware.BookShelf.BookShelfActivity$BookshelfAdapter.getView(BookShelfActivity.java:331)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1439)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1222)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:268)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:221)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:188)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:3569)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:3067)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:850)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
01-10 05:24:32.492: E/AndroidRuntime(2303):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this happens usually because you have a memory leak somewhere else, and then your app could croak anywhere but is most likely to run out of memory during a bitmap operation.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. Then I decided to try using Bitmaps instead of Drawables and I'm not getting the OutOfMemoryException anymore.

This is consuming less memory:

```
view.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filename ) );
```

than

```
view.setImageDrawable( Drawable.createFromPath( filename ) );
```